# How to send data and photo at same time to node js backend using axios in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send some form data and image to backend using axios but my code isn't working. When I send image alone it works and when i send data alone it works. But how to send both at same time:

I am using reactjs and useState:

```
const [roomData, setRoomData] = useState(data)
```

All my data are in roomData.

```
const [files, setfiles] = useState()
```

I have set my images in files variable using onchange on input tag and  setfiles(e.target.files)

I have appended all images from files in formdata variable using belows code

```
const submitHandler=async(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const formData= new FormData();
        Array.from(files).forEach(file=>{
            formData.append('photos', file)
        })

        const res= await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8000/api/sell_products',
            { formData, roomData }
        )

    }
```

Using this I only get roomData in backend as req.body. But when I console req.files it given undefined. Help

Comment: How can you get `roomData` when it isn't even mentioned in your `submitHandler` code?

Comment: i made roomData variable from useState

Comment: Oh, I see it now. I just had to scroll right. I suggested an edit to split that line up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append data in text in form data. Don't send it seperatly

```
const submitHandler=async(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData= new FormData();
    form.append('data', roomData);
    Array.from(files).forEach(file=>{
        formData.append('photos', file)
    })

    const res= await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/sell_products', { formData})

}
```

Comment: And how do i get them seperatly in node js backend. Can you help again

Comment: By seperatly what do mean? You can do req.body.data to get data in text and req.files to get an array of files. Use multer for file operation will be easier

Comment: req.body.data returns [object object] and i cannot access my roomdata now. But req.files works fine

Comment: I don't know if roomData is an object but what you can do is descturcute the object try console.log({...req.body.data});